# Javascript DateTime Comparision

Tags: javascript, datetime

Let's say I have like the following:
 **startDate: "2011-10-20 14:30"
 endDate: "2011-10-20 17:30"**

I want to compare startDate and endDate if startDate is greater than endDate. Essentially, the way I really want to compare is Date Object and Date Object, not string and string.

Anybody can help with this?

Comment: If you can guarantee that format you can just do a string compare with `>` and still get the right result. But is your question really "how do I convert a string in that format to a JS date object"?

Comment: I am not quite sure if we compare in string it would produce correct result. let me try it out!

Comment: It will work as a string compare as long as the format goes year then month then day and has a two-digit month, day, hour and minute, e.g., "2011-03-09 02:05". It won't work as a string compare if some of your dates have one-digit month or day, like "2011-3-9 2:05".

Answer (score 1):

If you replace the space in the strings with "T" you can parse them directly using the date constructor:

```
var startDate = new Date(('2011-10-20 14:30').replace(' ', 'T'));
var endDate = new Date(('2011-10-20 17:30').replace(' ', 'T'));

alert( startDate + ' is ' +  
      (startDate - endDate > 0? 'after ' : 'on or before ') +  endDate );
```

#### Edit

Or you can replace the '-' with '/' for IE and everyone else (I think...):

```
var startDate = new Date(('2011-10-20 14:30').replace(/-/g,'/'));
var endDate = new Date(('2011-10-20 17:30').replace(/-/g,'/'));
```

But a parsing function might be better.

Answer (score 0):

```
d1 = new Date(startDate);
d2 = new Date(endDate);
if (d1>d2) alert('greater');
```

Comment: As the dates are, they will result in an invalid date if passed directly to the `Date` constructor.